# Edit MySQL query to get likes from user from diffrent table in same query and show if liked or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hi Guys i got two tables the first on is called "posts" and looks like this

```
id    picture    title    description    poster    ip    posterid    .....
123   img-2.jpg  Title 1  Desc 1         Poster    xx    1
```

The second table is called "love" and looks like this

```
id    ip    userid    postid    created
1     xx    1         123       date
```

This is how my MySQL Query looks actually:

```
<?php

// Get records from the database
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");

    if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $postID = $row['id'];
    ?>

          <!-- POST ITEM START -->
          <div class="post-item">
            <div class="post-asset image">
              <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['picture']; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="post-header">
              <h3 class="post-title"><a href="#" data-loader="show"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></h3>
              <span class="post-category">

                <a class="favorite-button" href="#" data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-userid="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>"><span class="favorite-button-icon fa fa-star-o"></span></a>

              </span>

              <span class="post-date font17"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php $timeago=get_timeago(strtotime($row['created'])); echo $timeago;?></span>
              <span class="post-comments font17"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 1,3k Reaktionen</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-footer">
              <a href="#" class="post-author">
                <span class="author-img"><img src="img/avatar.png"></span>
                <span class="author-name">OnePost von<b><?php echo $row['poster']; ?></b></span>
              </a>
              <div class="post-extra">
                <!--<div class="add-favorite" id="heart-container"><span class="lovecount">112</span><input data-post="123" data-user="Jessica Jones" type="checkbox" id="toggle" onclick="myFunction(this)" checked><div id="twitter-heart" class=""></div></input></div>-->

                <div class="add-favorite" id="heart-container"><a href="#" title="Alle Loves anzeigen"><span class="lovecount"><?php echo $row['loves']; ?></span></a>

                <!--<input data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-userid="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>" type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="toggle love" onclick="myFunction(this)">-->
                <input data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-userid="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>" type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="toggle">

                  <div id="twitter-heart" class=""></div></input></div>
                <div class="post-share"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
                  <div class="social-links">
                    <a href="#" class="share-facebook social-links-a" data-network="Facebook" data-post="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-url="https://onepost.eu/neu/post.php"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="share-twitter social-links-a" data-network="Twitter" data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-url="https://onepost.eu/neu/post.php"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="share-google-plus social-links-a" data-network="Pinterest" data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-url="https://onepost.eu/neu/post.php"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="share-whatsapp social-links-a" data-network="WhatsApp" data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-url="https://onepost.eu/neu/post.php"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- POST ITEM END -->

          <div class="form-mini-divider"></div>

          <?php } ?>






          <div class="form-divider"></div> -->
        <div class="show_more_main" id="show_more_main<?php echo $postID; ?>">

          <button id="<?php echo $postID; ?>" class="show_more button circle block green">Mehr OnePosts</button>
          <button class="postloading button circle block green" style="display: none;">Lade...</button>


        </div>

        <?php } ?>
```

What i want to get done is now to get to know if the actual user with its Session id which is also the user id hast liked the post or not and display it in if or if not.

Comment: Where did you stuck? getting the data from the DB? Or displaying it in HTML? Don't say both, because that would be two questions.

Comment: i get stuck to find out the right query displaying it in html should be possible and i could figure it out @PaulSpiegel

Comment: Any Help? Or Ideas how to get the data in one quer and display it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN to the `love` table and check if the post is actually loved/liked with a `IS NOT NULL` condition:

```
<?php

// Get records from the database
    $stmt = $db->prepare("
        SELECT p.*, (l.postid IS NOT NULL) as is_liked
        FROM posts p
        LEFT JOIN love l
          ON  l.postid = p.id
          AND l.userid = ?
        ORDER BY p.id DESC
        LIMIT 10
    ");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $currentUserId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $postID = $row['id'];
    ?>

    [...]
```

You can access the values with `$row['is_liked']` which will contain either `1` or `0`.

You need to replace `$currentUserId` with the variable which holds the ID of current use. That could be `$_SESSION['userid']`.

Comment: Tried it out but shows no query and  a blank page do i do anything wrong?`// Include the database configuration file
    include 'inc/dbConfig.php';
    
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT p.*, (l.postid IS NOT NULL) as is_liked FROM posts p LEFT JOIN love l ON  l.postid = p.id AND l.userid = ? ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 10");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $currentUserId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $postID = $row['id'];`

Comment: Do you have the variable `$currentUserId`? Please read my last sentence in the answer.

Comment: hey buddy, yes replaced it actualy looking this way but shows nothing '// Include the database configuration file
    include 'inc/dbConfig.php';
    
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT p.*, (l.postid IS NOT NULL) as is_liked FROM posts p LEFT JOIN love l ON  l.postid = p.id AND l.userid = ? ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 10");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $postID = $row['id'];'

Comment: "White page" is not helping. Turn error reporting on. See: [how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments-mysqli-fetch-as)

Comment: he displays me this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /usr/www/users/onepos/onepost/neu/postline.php on line 172`

Comment: Knowing the problem? Any Idea?

Comment: What is your PHP version? It must be really old. [mysqli_stmt::get_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) is available since PHP 5.3 which was released 10 years ago.

Comment: got 5.3 any other ideas?

Comment: will update and see again looking forward that it runs and will accept your answer if works but i think so looks everything good right now

Comment: awesome my friend you saved my day is working and the failure or compliction was php version.